# Python socket io client does'n accept connection but node client does

Tags: python, node.js, socket.io

There is a node sever and I want to perform a socket connection with my client.
I can connect with node but python version doesn't connect.

what is wrong with python version?

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');


const socket = io("wss://winseller.turkmenexpress.ir", {
  auth: {
    token: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJwSWQiOiIyNyIsIm1vYmlsZSI6IjA5MTI3Mzk2Nzk0In0.moQMWb_I1CyhCJ9Gh4TLH8LiVwtE7h2wH4DPY-KEeT0"
  }
});

socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
  console.log('server is down');
})

socket.on('connect', function(data){
  console.log('socket is connected');
})
```

```
import socketio

sio = socketio.Client()
sio.connect('wss://winseller.turkmenexpress.ir',auth={
    'token': "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJwSWQiOiIyNyIsIm1vYmlsZSI6IjA5MTI3Mzk2Nzk0In0.moQMWb_I1CyhCJ9Gh4TLH8LiVwtE7h2wH4DPY-KEeT0"
  },wait=True, wait_timeout= 10
)


@sio.on('connect')
def connect():
  print('socket is connected')

@sio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect():
  print('server is down')
```

Comment: try `ws://winseller.turkmenexpress.ir`

Comment: @dean-van-greunen It doesn't work.

Comment: hi dadash. ``ws://`` using for ``http`` ans ``wss://`` using for ``tls`` or``https://``.

Comment: @User12 Hi brother, did you test that? all of parameter is real. I already test what you recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the code a bit just to check if this is working and seems fine.

```py
import socketio
print('start...')

sio = socketio.Client()
sio.connect('wss://winseller.turkmenexpress.ir',auth={
    'token': "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJwSWQiOiIyNyIsIm1vYmlsZSI6IjA5MTI3Mzk2Nzk0In0.moQMWb_I1CyhCJ9Gh4TLH8LiVwtE7h2wH4DPY-KEeT0"
  },wait=True, wait_timeout= 10
)

print('phase 1 ...', sio)

@sio.on('connect')
def connect():
  print('socket is connected')

@sio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect():
  print('server is down')


connect()
```

this is the result:

```
start...
phase 1 ... <socketio.client.Client object at 0x000001EC7FB96020>
socket is connected
```

So aside from the result what were you expecting ?

Comment: So you connected right? maybe problem is with my side. it's part of my project. I am really appreciated with your help.

Comment: yes, the question is what are you expecting to see as a result ?

Comment: "socket is connected". I don't see that. and when i emit event it doesn't get it. node version is totally fine.

Comment: I reinstall socket package and your code worked with it. thank you so mush.

Answer (score 2):

first reinstall your packages and then try to use `socketio` in this way:

```
sio = socketio.Client()

@sio.event
def connect():
    print('socket connected')

@sio.event
def my_message(data):
    print('message received with ', data)
    sio.emit('my response', {'response': 'my response'})

@sio.event
def disconnect():
    print('socket disconnected from server')

sio.connect('wss://winseller.turkmenexpress.ir', auth={
    'token': "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJwSWQiOiIyNyIsIm1vYmlsZSI6IjA5MTI3Mzk2Nzk0In0.moQMWb_I1CyhCJ9Gh4TLH8LiVwtE7h2wH4DPY-KEeT0"
  })
sio.wait()
```

Comment: thanks for response, I tried it but connection massage didn't shows up. I still get "socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError: One or more namespaces failed to connect".

Comment: first disable your authentication system and check using this connection: ``sio.connect('wss://winseller.turkmenexpress.ir', wait_timeout = 10)``. if this is ok, then try to authorized your client.

Comment: I don't access to server it's just an API to use.

Comment: ok. ``wait_timeout `` dont resolve your problem?

Comment: thanks bro, I reinstalled my packages and your code is working fine.